# perform function in multiple csv files iteratively

Tags: r, csv

I have a lot of csv files stored in a folder. i.e. file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, etc, etc
each csv file contains the same measurements for each object.
a file looks like this:

```
ID     time    measuremment1    measurement2    measurement3   
 1     5       12               324             123
 1     6       123              654             45
 1     3       346              556             548
```

another one looks like this:

```
ID    time    measurement1    measurement2    measurement3
 2     2       234             345            253
 2     8       35              998            316
 2     17      515             1005           323 
 2     50      156             155            616
```

and so on. in addition, I have a data frame with several calculations I want to perform for each of my objects(files), which looks like this:

```
calc<- data.frame(mean1 = mean(measurement1), var1 = var(measurement1),
sd1 = sd(measurement1), mean2 = mean(measurement2), var2 = var(measurement2),
sd2 = sd(measurement2))
```

etc, etc. what I want to do is find a way to read each csv file iteratively and perform these calculations for each object. finally, I would like to either export them in a separate csv file (to have the information I need concentrated), or either print it in R console and copy it from there to a text or excel file.
I am working in R
can anyone provide any help with this?
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### Option 1: Read in all files, combine into a single data frame and then summarize

With this method, all the data files are loaded into an R list.

```
dat = sapply(list.files(pattern="csv$"), function(file) {
  df = read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
  df$source = file
  df
}, simplify=FALSE)

dat = bind_rows(dat)
```

Summarize by `ID`:

```
dat.summary = dat %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE), var(., na.rm=TRUE), sd(., na.rm=TRUE)), -time)
```

Or in the newer `dplyr` idiom:

```
dat.summary = dat %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(matches("measurement")), 
               funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE), var(., na.rm=TRUE), sd(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

#### Option 2: Read and summarize each individual file, then bind the individual summaries into a single summary data frame

This way you load only one data file into memory at a time.

```
dat.summary = sapply(list.files(pattern="csv$"), function(file) {
  df = read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

  # Summarise by ID
  df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(matches("measurement")), 
                 funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE), var(., na.rm=TRUE), sd(., na.rm=TRUE)))
})

dat.summary = bind_rows(dat.summary)
```

#### Now save the summary:

```
write.csv(dat.summary, "my_summary.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

or

```
library(xlsx)

write.xlsx(dat.summary, "my_summary.xlsx", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I am looking at option two, since it best fits what I want to achieve.
can you please expand on what you are doing in the first part?
I am trying to fit my data into your code but getting errors. thank you

Comment: Please add an update to your question with the code you're running and the errors you're getting.

Comment: thank you for this. I have been trying to fix other issues that turned up while running this code. it seems that it is somehow working. However, I do not initially understand what this stands for:
     summarise_at(vars(matches("measurement")).
Secondly, I get the following error:
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :  unused argument (stringAsFactors = FALSE). Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Just another typo in my code. Should be `stringsAsFactors` rather than `stringAsFactors`.

Comment: `summarise_at` is a `dplyr` function that allows you to select which columns to summarise. In this case, we choose columns (`vars`) whose name includes the string "measurement". We choose the summary functions with `funs`. For more info, see [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/), as well as the `dplyr` help.

Answer (score 2):

Alex,
This is a multi-step process.

Here's how I would do:

Step 1: Read all files using read.csv function.

```
csv1<-read.csv("1.csv")
csv2<-read.csv("1.csv")
csv3<-read.csv("1.csv")
```

Step 2: 
You would need to combine them in one csv file.

```
csv1$type<-"1"
csv2$type<-"2"
csv3$type<-"3"
csv<-rbind(csv1, csv2,csv3)
```

Make sure that columns match otherwise the last step above will throw an error.

Step3:

Research how you can find summary statistic using dplyr. There are plenty of examples here on SO. I can help only after seeing that you have tried by yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I don't think this is viable. I have thousands of csv files and the concept is to do this iteratively and not one by one. moreover, I do know about summary statistic libraries in R, but there are loads of other numbers I am extracting. what I wrote in the description is just an example.